# What license should I use for an app released under my employer's account?

Tags: licensing, commercial

My company is offering an Amazon Echo and and Amazon gift card for employees who develop a Skill. There are some requirements with it.

- It must be completed during personal time (the learning and developing is not billable)
- It must be published using the company's Amazon account

It's a promotion for getting us developers to learn how to work with the Echo and also as a portfolio for picking up Echo related work from clients.

My question is, how should I copyright/license my app and code so that I can

- still use it in my own portfolio
- publish it under my own Amazon account if the company decides to pull the Skill
- or I can publish my own (maybe modified) version at the same time.

There isn't any requirements for the code to be shared with the company (they are offering to let us use their private repo) though I'm not opposed to sharing so long as I can still keep ownership and do all the things listed above.

Comment: These seem to be questions to ask your employer.  The first thing to find out is who will own the copyright.  It appears to me that you will, but it's best to be sure.  I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson it is very common to have a contract that gives all IP to your employer (to avoid the "ah, but I invented it/first wrote it when I was not on the clock!" scenario)

Comment: Sounds like your employer is a jerk: 'we want you to do stuff we care about and not pay you except in chickens.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer to this question can be, "What does your employment agreement say?" If it says that you own your off-the-clock work, then there is no 'best' license to use; use whatever you like. If it's "all your bases belong to us," then don't ask us, ask them.